# Understanding Vectorized Code In R

Tags: r, vectorization, apply

I'm trying to understand the answer to this question using R and I'm struggling a lot.

The dataset for the R code can be found with this code

```
library(devtools)
install_github("genomicsclass/GSE5859Subset")
library(GSE5859Subset)
data(GSE5859Subset) ##this loads the three tables you need
```

Here is the question

Write a function that takes a vector of values e and a binary vector group coding two groups, and returns the p-value from a t-test: t.test( e[group==1], e[group==0])$p.value.

Now define g to code cases (1) and controls (0) like this g <- factor(sampleInfo$group)

Next use the function apply to run a t-test for each row of geneExpression and obtain the p-value. What is smallest p-value among all these t-tests?

The answer provided is

```
myttest <- function(e,group){
    x <- e[group==1]
    y <- e[group==0]
    return( t.test(x,y)$p.value )
    }
g <- factor(sampleInfo$group)
pvals <- apply(geneExpression,1,myttest, group=g)
min( pvals )
```

Which gives you the answer of 1.406803e-21.

What exactly is the input of the "e" argument of the myttest function when you run this? Is it possible to write this function as a formula like

```
t.test(DV ~ sampleInfo$group)
```

The t test is comparing the gene expression values of the 24 people (the values of which I believe are in the "geneExpression" matrix) by what group they were 
in which you can find in sampleInfo's "group" column. I've run t tests so many times in R, but for some reason I can't wrap my mind around what's going on in this code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You question seems to be about understanding the function `apply()`.

For the technical description, see `?apply`.

My quick explanation: the `apply()` line of code in your question applies the following function to each of the rows of `geneExpression`

```
myttest(e=x, group=g)
```

where `x` is a placeholder for each row.

To help make sense of it, a `for` loop version of that `apply()` line would look something like:

```
N <- nrows(geneExpression)   #so we don't have to type this twice
pvals <- numeric(N)          #empty vector to store results

# what 'apply' does (but it does it very quickly and with less typing from us)
for(i in 1:N) {
    pvals[i] <- myttest(geneExpression[i,], group=g[i])
}
```

Comment: This is great! thanks! One question though. Wouldn't it be `group=g` not `g[i]`?

Comment: Maybe.  I didn't actually install the package from github so I was just guessing at the data in the various objects.